# how to arrange views in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best approach to arrange four views in layout ?

In portrait mode I would like: [image]

On screen rotation to landscape I would like to change layout with animation to [image]

How I should to arrange these views ? I'm thinking about 2 `LinearLayout's` and to change after roatation to one `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation.. Or `GridLayout` ?

Comment: I think that a GridView is a bit much for just 4 views, I would go for using LinearLayouts in the way you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide two layout files. The portrait has 3x LinearLayout

```
v

 -h

 -h
```

and landscape just one horizontal.

In terms of performance you should not fear a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two different layouts and create a refs.xml file in your nornal values folder, if you don't have one already, in that do something like;

```
<item name="plus_buttons" type="layout">@layout/plus_buttons_small_grid</item>
```

And then for screenwidths that you think the horizontal arrangement will fit perfectly, say 600dp, create a folder called values-sw600dp in your res directory and do something in another refs.xml in that folder like this;

```
<item name="plus_buttons" type="layout">@layout/plus_buttons_large</item>
```

With this you have two layout files that are independent of each other and work for all the desired screen widths